# Android - Open dialogue builder in fancy way

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-popupwindow

I have been using android dialog builder by inflating layouts in it. Everything is working fine and perfect. But now, I want to change the way of opening of the dialog builder. I want open the dialog builder like the swipe card. .i.e. From left to right OR top to bottom etc.

I know stackoverflow is not all about asking questions, but showing some effort at least. But issue is, I am not able to find any examples or clues on it.
Need some advice, or reference to be followed.

Thanks!

Dialog Opening Code:

```
   final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.prompt_dialoge);
    dialog.setTitle("Draw your signature below");

   Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        }
    });
   dialog.show();
```

Comment: please add the code related to show dialog.

Comment: It is too easy. Everyone know how to open a dialog builder. I just wanted to know how to change the way it is being opened. I want to open the builder in a swipe card way. That's it.

Comment: I just want to see your codes to know how to create your dialog, There are many ways to show a dialog.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style to your `new Dialog()` constructor like below.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(main.this, R.style.DialogStyle);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.prompt_dialoge);
dialog.setTitle("Draw your signature below");

Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Add this style to your `styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="DialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_right</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_right</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="00%p" />

</set>
```

**slide_out_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="000%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

Comment: What about the animation in anim folder? Can you please give me a demo code?

Comment: @kamranbhatti585 updated my answer and added animation xml file contents

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. Working perfect. Can you tell me how to shake the dialog in slide_in_right.xml?